# Obtaining the CSRF Token ID from web site using c#

Tags: c#

I have a situation where i will have to download the file from the website. It is a secured site (https) and also It requires the client certificate authentication.

I have a client certificate and managed to get in. After logged in, when i tried to download the file, i am not able to download the file. In turn, the file contains the html with csrftoken. How to get this token id? In order to download the file i need this token. Could someone share what kind of authentication this, and how can i get the csrf token id using c#.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not authentication. Its security to prevent [cross site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

The technique is:

- Any state changing operation requires a secure random token (e.g CSRF
  token) to prevent against CSRF attacks.
- Unique per user & per user session
- Tied to a single user session
- Large random value
- Generated by a cryptographically secure random number generator
- The CSRF token is added as a hidden field for forms or within the URL
  if the state changing operation occurs via a GET
- The server rejects the requested action if the CSRF token fails
  validation

In your case the workflow should be near to this:

1. Client make a request (tipicaly a `HTTP GET`) to see info in their
   screen.
2. The response HTML has a `hidden field` in the generated `Form` with
   the CSRF token.
3. Client makes a `POST` when click on a button with the following data: File identification he
   wants to download and the CSRF token.
4. Server checks that this token is valid for this `POST`.
5. Server sends the file bites to the response stream.

So, if you want to download a file programmatically with C# I think that you should do a `GET` first as if you were a webBrowser; retrieve the CSRF token parsing the responsed HTML and send a `POST` whith the file and the CSRF token.

Comment: Thanks jlvaquero. Parsing the html is the only way to obtain the CSRF Token?

Comment: I dont know the system you are requesting so I can not give you an answer ti that. Im just guessing based on generic way of csrf.

Comment: I am calling from C#. The CSRF token is in body as a hidden field. I don't get this token in cookies or headers. Only way to access this token is from the html body.

Comment: Then, it seems the only way but in c# is easy to do.